# CSS applied to a class hover state

Tags: css, hover

I have this working for the menu link color:

```
a.navPage-subMenu-action.navPages-action {
color:#ffffff;   
}

I searched on here for a solution, and it would appear that it's as simple as:
a.navPage-subMenu-action.navPages-action:hover {
color:#ffffff;   
}
```

But that is not working. It is a BigCommerce site and I am trying to change the color from the existing red (on hover). The hover color wouldn't be white - I'm only using that for testing to see if the red goes away.

Comment: You can use devTools to see if your custom CSS is overridden by other CSS.

Comment: If you have the site URL, I'll be able to figure this out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the !important tag this should override your themes product hover.

Comment: Thank you - I'll give that a try. I found the CSS buried in the BigCommerce backend for this section, but I want to try your solution as well. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: you would add this to your childs theme style.css file so whenever there is an update to the plugin, it doesn't get overwritten.